# How to expand div dimenssions when dragging a child element to its borders?

Tags: javascript, draggable

I'm building a kind of board that contains draggable elements, and I want when someone drag an element to the bounds of the board, the board get expanded, something like Figma or Adobe XD workspace (but without using canvas), I had multiple attempts but I couldn't to implement it correctly

Comment: have you tried using the [drop event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drop_event) ?

Comment: @Sina drop event isn't in my use case, only dragging/moving elements around.